# Slow git clone and fetch

Tags: git

I setuped gitosis on a linux server following this tutorial:

http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

We are using git on our windows machines with TortoiseGit and msysgit.

Pushing changes to the server is pretty fast, but when we want to clone or fetch changes from the remote server, it begins really fast (800k/s) and then drop pretty fast to around 3 to 30k/s and it can take forever to update.  git-pull for small update is fast, but as soon as we have to download something of more than a few MB, it is slow.

We are switching from SVN to git and this is holding us back from using git full time.

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that it starts fast, then slows way down would make me wonder if there is some traffic-limiting device involved. Are you running over ssh or git: or http: ?
- Greg

Comment: We found out after some testing that SSH was the problem with msysgit.  When we used scp to transfer a file to our server with msysgit, the transfer started fast and then slowed down.  We tested from a Mac computer, did the same command and it was fast.  So there's something wrong with OpenSSH in the msysgit distribution.

Comment: May be some kind of traffic shaping somewhere? Is the speed stable after slowdown?

Comment: Are You under a vpn connection ?

Comment: You may want to check out gitolite. Gitosis hasn't been updated for a while. Also gitolite is very easy to setup :)

Comment: This sounds like the server repo isn't well packed and the daemon packs it on the fly in order to conserve bandwidth, but ends up taking longer since the packing is very resource intensive. What are the CPU & memory specs on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Like you were able to identify, this is a client issue, not the *server fault*.

If you want, you can configure TortoiseGit to use Putty's plink instead of its custom implementation.

Then you can customize the default settings using Putty.

In Putty "Default Settings", enable the following:

1. **SSH -> Auth: "Allow agent forwarding"** (I believe this is the one that changes "everything")
2. SSH -> "Enable Compression"
3. Session -> Select "Default Settings" -> **Save**

For me, this resulted in going from 143.00 KiB/s to **4.50 MiB/s**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you solved the issue but thought I would add my experience. When we tried to implement git we discovered that clones were much slower when done on a NFS mount so we now advise everyone to use local disks.